# Get html using Python requests?

Tags: python, html, python-requests

I am trying to teach myself some basic web scraping.  Using Python's requests module, I was able to grab html for various websites until I tried this:

```
>>> r = requests.get('http://www.wrcc.dri.edu/WRCCWrappers.py?sodxtrmts+028815+por+por+pcpn+none+mave+5+01+F')
```

Instead of the basic html that is the source for this page, I get:

```
>>> r.text
'\x1f\ufffd\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\ufffd]o\u06f8\x12\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd+\ufffd]...

>>> r.content
b'\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\xed\x9d]o\xdb\xb8\x12\x86\xef\xfb+\x88]\x14h...
```

I have tried many combinations of get/post with every syntax I can guess from the documentation and from SO and other examples.  I don't understand what I am seeing above, haven't been able to turn it into anything I can read, and can't figure out how to get what I actually want.  My question is, how do I get the html for the above page?

Comment: Seems to work here, just tried it with the exact url on Python 2.7

Comment: `test = html.fromstring(r.text)`

Comment: Id highly recommend BeautifulSoup for web scraping http://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#. It will make your life a heck of a lot easier.

Comment: u can use urllib3 also it is same as requests

Comment: @vikasdumca: `requests` **is built on top of** `urllib3`. The problem is the server here, however.

Comment: @Ron: you first need to get HTML text, which the OP doesn't have. It is gzipped data.

Comment: @Mani: that'd only work if you actually had HTML data, not compressed data because the server screwed up.

Comment: works fine for me using requests, what version of requests are you using?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: the server seems to respond rather randomly; I was wondering why I got uncompressed data for *one* response but not for another. I get an injected `<!DOCTYPE>` header. Explicitly asking for uncompressed data seems to work more reliably.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The server in question is giving you a *gzipped response*. The server is also *very broken*; it sends the following headers:

```
$ curl -D - -o /dev/null -s -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate' http://www.wrcc.dri.edu/WRCCWrappers.py?sodxtrmts+028815+por+por+pcpn+none+mave+5+01+F
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 06 Jan 2015 17:46:49 GMT
Server: Apache
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"><html xmlns="http: //www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en-US">
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 3659
Content-Type: text/html
```

The `<!DOCTYPE..>` line there is **not a valid HTTP header**. As such, the remaining headers past `Server` are *ignored*. Why the server interjects that is unclear; in all likely hood `WRCCWrappers.py` is a CGI script that doesn't output headers but does include a double newline after the doctype line, duping the Apache server into inserting additional headers there.

As such, `requests` also doesn't detect that the data is gzip-encoded. The data is all there, you just have to decode it. Or you could if it wasn't rather incomplete.

The work-around is to tell the server not to bother with compression:

```
headers = {'Accept-Encoding': 'identity'}
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

and an uncompressed response is returned.

Incidentally, on Python 2 the HTTP header parser is not so strict and manages to declare the doctype a header:

```
>>> pprint(dict(r.headers))
{'<!doctype html public "-//w3c//dtd xhtml 1.0 transitional//en" "dtd/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"><html xmlns="http': '//www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en-US">',
 'connection': 'Keep-Alive',
 'content-encoding': 'gzip',
 'content-length': '3659',
 'content-type': 'text/html',
 'date': 'Tue, 06 Jan 2015 17:42:06 GMT',
 'keep-alive': 'timeout=5, max=100',
 'server': 'Apache',
 'vary': 'Accept-Encoding'}
```

and the `content-encoding` information survives, so there `requests` decodes the content for you, as expected.

Comment: Yep, it is a python 3 problem. Works perfectly every time using python2

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: no, it is a server problem. Python 2 just happens to not validate the header properly. It works in Python 2 but you get the `<!DOCTYPE...>` line as a header.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: It turns out that when I use the work around, the response content is corrupted by the addition of an occasional extra characters starting with the data for 1934.  Based on your explanation, I instead decompressed the response content with `zlib.decompress(r.content, 16+zlib.MAX_WBITS)`, which seems to have handled all issues.

Comment: FYI, the HTTP headers have now been fixed for this URL. I apologize for the error.

Comment: @Grant: :-D No need to apologise to me though.

Answer (score 13):

The HTTP headers for this URL have now been fixed.

```
>>> import requests
>>> print requests.__version__
2.5.1
>>> r = requests.get('http://www.wrcc.dri.edu/WRCCWrappers.py?sodxtrmts+028815+por+por+pcpn+none+mave+5+01+F')
>>> r.text[:100]
u'\n<!DOCTYPE html>\n<HTML>\n<HEAD><TITLE>Monthly Average of Precipitation, Station id: 028815</TITLE></H'
>>> r.headers
{'content-length': '3672', 'content-encoding': 'gzip', 'vary': 'Accept-Encoding', 'keep-alive': 'timeout=5, max=100', 'server': 'Apache', 'connection': 'Keep-Alive', 'date': 'Thu, 12 Feb 2015 18:59:37 GMT', 'content-type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8'}
```

Answer (score 12):

Here is an example using the [BeautifulSoup](https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/) library. It "makes it easy to scrape information from web pages."

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import requests

# request web page
resp = requests.get("http://example.com")

# get the response text. in this case it is HTML
html = resp.text

# parse the HTML
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

# print the HTML as text
print(soup.body.get_text().strip())
```

and the result

```
Example Domain
This domain is for use in illustrative examples in documents. You may use this
    domain in literature without prior coordination or asking for permission.
More information...
```

Answer (score 9):

I'd solve that problem in a more simple way. Just import `html` library to decode HTML special characters:

```py
import html

r = requests.get('http://www.wrcc.dri.edu/WRCCWrappers.py?sodxtrmts+028815+por+por+pcpn+none+mave+5+01+F')

print(html.unescape(r.text))
```

Comment: +rep 8 years later