# Selenium Python How to get web content from href without click on it

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have logged in the web by using Selenium with Python. Now I want to find all the href links and download/save the webpage of the links without using `.click()`.
The href is something like

```
<a href="project.cfm?CFID=162805&amp;CFTOKEN=98566707&amp;fromlist=1&amp;project_refid=10700290" target="_parent">sth (2) - 2 xox | oo - xx dd </a>
```

[image: link example]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get html using Python requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27803503/get-html-using-python-requests)

Comment: hi! so u want to enter the href URL and save the websites html?

Answer (score -1):

First you can get the links using below

```
listOFLinks =driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a")
```

then iterate through the list

```
for link in listOFLinks
url = link.getAttribute("href");
```

You can print the url variable or save it into an array as per your requirement

Comment: This doesn't save the webpage as requested.