# For python, what does it mean for <class 'requests.models.Response'>

Tags: python, class, python-requests

I tries to use Requests library in python for crawling, I first imported the requests module,and then I use get function to call the website for getting a response named r, but I can not understand why the type of r is class,could you please tell me why ,thank you very much.

I also want to check the request header, I checked some documents, it says that I can use r.request.headers, what does the request here mean, is it a method?

```
>>> import requests
>>> r=requests.get("http://www.baidu.com")
>>> type(r)
<class 'requests.models.Response'>
```

Comment: this is simply a class....follow this link to het idea about how to use get...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27803503/get-html-using-python-requests

Comment: check the output of `help(r)` . You'll get a clear picture of what is the base class, from where it is inherited from and few definitions!

Comment: That's just how the class is represented.

Comment: The response is an object derived from class `requests.models.Response`, makes sense, no?

Comment: @alfasin, the response is an object or instance here ?

Comment: `r` is of type `requests.models.Response`... what is your question?

Comment: @jing a (class) object *is* an instance (of a class). These terms express the same thing

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, thanks for the question!

Answer (score 13):

You're getting a `Response` object after you fire off the request.  To get data from the response object you need to access the property you're after, e.g. `r.status_code`, `r.text`, etc.

See [this documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) for more details.

Comment: Hi,Jerry, does the object here mean instance or just class object ?

Comment: @jing Instance of a class.

Comment: Documentation link is broken

Answer (score 5):

For the <class 'requests.models.Response'> has following attributes:

```
['_content', '_content_consumed', '_next', 'status_code', 'headers', 'raw', 'url', 'encoding', 'history', 'reason', 'cookies', 'elapsed', 'request', 'connection', '__module__', '__doc__', '__attrs__', '__init__', '__enter__', '__exit__', '__getstate__', '__setstate__', '__repr__', '__bool__', '__nonzero__', '__iter__', 'ok', 'is_redirect', 'is_permanent_redirect', 'next', 'apparent_encoding', 'iter_content', 'iter_lines', 'content', 'text', 'json', 'links', 'raise_for_status', 'close', '__dict__', '__weakref__', '__hash__', '__str__', '__getattribute__', '__setattr__', '__delattr__', '__lt__', '__le__', '__eq__', '__ne__', '__gt__', '__ge__', '__new__', '__reduce_ex__', '__reduce__', '__subclasshook__', '__init_subclass__', '__format__', '__sizeof__', '__dir__', '__class__']
```

Answer (score 1):

It is response from HTTP request. If this is a REST API that you are making a call to, you can convert the response to JSON by calling r.json().

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30749405)

Answer (score -1):

Its just a response to the request you're sending, hope this helps :)