# Python requests lib doesn't work with LinkedIn

Tags: python, debugging, https, request, python-requests

Sample code:

```
import requests
print requests.get("https://www.linkedin.com/")
```

I get: `<Response [200]>`

Simple curl request does work:

```
curl "https://www.linkedin.com/"
```

Comment: 200 means you made a valid request and got a good response....

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Response 200 means good connection.

Comment: I think OP was expecting `requests` to give back the `HTML` like `curl` does.

Comment: The Response object you're seeing (i.e. `<Response [200]>`) contains that data. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27803503/get-html-using-python-requests) for accessing it.

Comment: one look at the [documenation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) would tell you how to fix it. RTM

Answer (score 2):

If you get `<Response [200]>` that means that it worked properly. You should refer to the [documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) for unpacking this `Response` object to get the data inside of it.

E.g.:

```
>>> r = requests.get('https://linkedin.com/')
>>> r.text
'<!DOCTYPE html> ...'
```

Answer (score 2):

The requests.get() function returns a Response object that contains attributes about the status_code, headers, and content:

`[In]: type(requests.get("https://www.linkedin.com/")`

`[Out]: <class 'requests.models.Response'>`.

I would recommend saving the returned Response into a variable:

`response = requests.get("https://www.linkedin.com/")`

Then you can access the contents of the Response using `response.json()` if it is a JSON file or `response.text` if it is an html page.

In your use case, `response.text` should return the same thing as `curl "https://www.linkedin.com/"`.