# Accessing API through request but getting errors in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to access an API and it is mentioned that it gives in HTML. I went through these answers

([Get html using Python requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27803503/get-html-using-python-requests))  but I am not getting my results. I just wanted to make sure I am doing it correctly as I am getting error like this ("'`{"request":{"category_id":"717234","command":"category"},"data":{"error":"invalid or missing api_key'"` Is this API not working ? Is there any way to get HTML data and convert them to CSV or excel?
**Here is the code which I am using.**

```
import requests
URL = "https://api.eia.gov/category?api_key=YOUR_API_KEY_HERE&category_id=717234"
r = requests.get(url = URL)
r.text[:100]
```

Comment: you can use this link to get a key https://www.eia.gov/opendata/register.php

Comment: That makes sense I only had to register with that and it would send API key. Thanks Ghasseen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using a invalid api the link to your html page is not working :

```
import requests
URL = "https://api.eia.gov/category?api_key=YOUR_API_KEY_HERE&category_id=717234"
headers = {'Accept-Encoding': 'identity'}
r = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)
print(r.text[:100])
```

output:

```
{"request":{"category_id":"717234","command":"category"},"data":{"error":"invalid or missing api_key
```

i try to change the link of the link with that one given in the answer that you put the link and i get a result :

```
import requests
URL = "http://www.wrcc.dri.edu/WRCCWrappers.py?sodxtrmts+028815+por+por+pcpn+none+mave+5+01+F"
headers = {'Accept-Encoding': 'identity'}
r = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)
print(r.text[:100])
```

output:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML>
<HEAD><TITLE>Average of Precipitation, Station id: 028815</TITLE></HEAD>
<BO
```

as a solution  you can use an external api  the devoloper mode of that api : https://www.eia.gov//developer// or check this link to get a key :https://www.eia.gov/opendata/

Answer (score 0):

Its not an error.
seems to me like youre missing your API KEY.

this is what wrote in the link you put:

```
{"request":{"category_id":"717234","command":"category"},"data":{"error":"invalid or missing api_key. For key registration, documentation, and examples see https:\/\/www.eia.gov\/developer\/"}}
```

Comment: Yes thats correct it is mentioned in the website that this Key can be accessed, so I was just thinking if there is any other way or correct code to access it.

Comment: Which api are you trying to access?