# find substrings between two string

Tags: python, regex

I have a string like this:

```
string = r'''<img height="233" src="monline/" title="email example" width="500" ..
title="second example title"  width="600"...
title="one more title"...> '''
```

I am trying to get anything that appears as title (title="Anything here")
I have already tried this but it does not work correctly.

```
re.findall(r'title=\"(.*)\"',string)
```

Comment: Regex is not nice way to parse html. Use html parsers.

Comment: The requests library using xpath is probably the way to go: https://pypi.org/project/requests-html/

Comment: [Parsing HTML with regex is a hard job](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4234491/372239)
HTML and regex are not good friends. Use a parser, it is simpler, faster and much more maintainable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your Regex is too Greedy. You can try something like [this](https://regex101.com/r/Z0cBJH/1)

```
re.findall(r'title=\"(?P<title>[\w\s]+)\"', string)
```

As @Austin and @Plato77 said in the comments, there is a better way to parse HTML in python. See other [SO Answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11709079/parsing-html-using-python) for more context. There are a few common tools for this like:

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html
- https://www.simplifiedpython.net/parsing-html-in-python/
- https://github.com/psf/requests-html  /  [Get html using Python requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27803503/get-html-using-python-requests)

If you would like to read more on performance testing of different python HTML parsers you can learn more [here](http://www.ianbicking.org/blog/2008/03/python-html-parser-performance.html)

Comment: Thanks this works fine!

Comment: @mahhos, I'm glad this answer was useful. Please accept answers as correct once your issue has been solved. [Learn how](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow)

Answer (score 0):

As @Austin and @Plato77 said in the comments, there is a better way to parse HTML in python. I stand by this too, but if you want to get it done through regex this may help

```
c = re.finditer(r'title=[\"]([a-zA-Z0-9\s]+)[\" ]', string)

for i in c:
    print(i.group(1))
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that the next " symbol is parsed as a character and is  considered part of the (.*) of your RE. For your usecase, you can use only letters and numbers.